# Transition duration not working on bootstrap button

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, css-transitions

I am trying to add transition effect on some bootstrap buttons.

The problem is with height and width properties. These change straight away without considering the the transition duration property.

Note that all other properties change within described duration (2s in this case).

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      1 of 2
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      2 of 2
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      1 of 3
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      2 of 3
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      3 of 3
    </div>
  </div> 
  <button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#infoModal" class="btn btn-outline-warning mt-5 mb-3 3mr-3 ">Learn More</button>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.col {
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
  padding: 10px;
}

.btn-outline-warning {

    border-color: white;
    transition: all;
    transition-duration: 2s;


  }

  .btn-outline-warning:hover {

    border-color: rgb(255, 136, 0);
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    transform: rotate(20deg);
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    }
```

Here is my JSFiddle for more clarification and demonstration.

https://jsfiddle.net/p34mjfr5/11/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `transition` on one of your `css` property you need to set default value on it first, then change it on hover. specially those propery that need size like `px` or etc.. `width` or `height` following this rule.

```
.btn-outline-warning {
  border-color: white;
  transition: 2s all ease;
  width: 200px; /* default value */
  height: 50px; /* default value */
}

.btn-outline-warning:hover {
  border-color: rgb(255, 136, 0);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  transform: rotate(20deg);
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bpwjvsg4/)**